# 2 columns into 1, excluding a predefined value

Tags: mysql, activerecord

Say I have the following table:

```
messages
-------
id
sender
recipient
msg
```

I would like to fetch a user's conversations, but excluding himself, so that I end up with the columns: `id, user, msg`. `user` will be the other person. Obviously the user we want to exclude is known.

I thought of something like: `CONCAT(sender,"-",recipient)`, and then replace `idu-` or `-idu` with nothing. But I'm hoping there's something cleaner!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT(sender,"-",recipient),'idu-',''),'-idu','')
```

Comment: Yes that's the solution I thought about, but it's not very clean and I was wondering if there was a better way to do this